# run time error with function convert from string to int

Tags: c++, string

I have a string contains numbers but also contains spaces between them, i need to convert the string to int and store them in an int array .

Th following function produces a run time error

```
void fun(string  m)
{
    string temp;
    int j = 0;
    int h = 0;
    int d;
    int arr[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < m.length(); i++)
        {
            while (m[i] != ' ')
                temp[j++] = m[i];

            d = atoi(temp.c_str());
            arr[h++] = d;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(arr); i++)
        {
            cout << arr[i];
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making several mistakes in your code.

1. You have not initialized `temp` to contain anything, but you are trying to index into its characters.  Instead of `temp[j++] = m[i]`, you need to use `temp += m[i];` or `temp.push_back(m[i]);` or `temp.append(&m[i], 1);`.  Or consider using an [`std::ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream) to gather the characters, and then call its `str()` method to extract the final `std::string` value.
2. you are not incrementing `i` in your `while` loop.  As soon as the `for` loop reaches a non-whitespace character, your `while` loop will end up running endlessly, continuously (and unsuccessfully) trying to append the same character to `temp`.
3. you are not doing any bounds checking to make sure your `for` loop does not exceed `arr`'s max capacity of 10 numbers.
4. you are misusing `sizeof()`.  `sizeof(arr)` returns the number of bytes that `arr` occupies in memory (`10 * sizeof(int)`, which is 20 or 40 bytes, depending on your compiler's implementation of `int`).  It is not the number of elements in the array (10).  So you will exceed the bounds of the array trying to display 20/40 numbers instead of 10 numbers.

Your code is more complicated than it needs to be.  You can use a [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) for parsing and let it ignore whitespace for you.  Use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) or other dynamically-sized container to receive the parsed numbers.

```
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

void fun(string  m)
{
    std::istreamstream iss(m);
    std::vector<int> vec;
    int num;

    vec.reserve(10); // optional

    while (iss >> num) {
        vec.push_back(num);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << vec[i];
    }
    /*
    alternatively:
    for (std::vector<int>::iterator iter = vec.begin(); iter != vec.end(); ++iter) {
        std::cout << *iter;
    }
    */
    /*
    alternatively (C++11 and later):
    for (auto i: vec) {
        std::cout << i;
    }
    */
    /*
    alternatively (C++11 and later):
    std::for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](int &n){ std::cout << n; });
    */
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for  your great answer, can you just give me what exactly `istreamstream` do ? I read more but still not clear for me

Comment: `std::istringstream` is an input stream for reading formatted data from a `std::string`.  Similar to `std::cin` for console input, `std::ifstream` for file input, etc. I have added links to documentation for `std::istringstream` (and `std::ostringstream` and `std::vector`).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a `stringstream` for this vs. rolling your own implementation.

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::stringstream ss("1 2 3 4 5 6 7");
    auto head = std::istream_iterator<int>(ss);
    auto tail = std::istream_iterator<int>();
    while(head!=tail)
    {
        std::cout << *head << "\n";
        ++head;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

if you're receiving the `string` in a method you can easily adapt the function above to create an empty `stringstream` and then pass it the string.

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string astring = "1 2 3 4 5 6";
    std::stringstream ss;

    ss << astring;
    auto head = std::istream_iterator<int>(ss);
    auto tail = std::istream_iterator<int>();
    while(head!=tail)
    {
        std::cout << *head << "\n";
        ++head;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do `for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(arr); i++)`

The `sizeof()` operator gives you the size of something in bytes, which for an array of 10 `int`s probably amounts to 40.  You need to use something like this:

```
#define COUNTOF(x) ((x)/sizeof((x)[0]))

for (int i = 0; i < COUNTOF(arr); i++)
```

Comment: I have change it to constant `for (int i = 0; i < 4 ; i++)` but still have an error

Comment: Well, then, that's probably a different error.  Having one error in your code does not mean that it is the only error.  It would greatly help if you explained precisely what error you get, precisely on which line, and precisely with what value of `m`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your while loop, J is 0 the first iteration through the While loop and gets incremented the first time it's called while also trying to assign it to the next letter.

Despite this issue I'd suggest using a string stream for this problem like others have said. 
[Here's a good reference.](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/)